# Problem understanding 'loss of solutions' when solving second-order ODE 'parametrically'

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand why I cannot obtain the 2 general solutions to a second order ODE when attempting to solve 'parametrically'.

For example, when attempting to solve y''+3y'+2y =0 you could just use the standard method of solving the auxiliary equation, but if you use the substitution z=y'+2y then z'=y''+2y' so z'+z=0 which has solution $z = \pm Ae^{-x}$, now solving for y using the integrating factor method gives $y = \pm Ae^{-x}$ ( from $ \pm Ae^{x}=e^{2x}y' + 2e^{2x}y $ after multiplying through by $e^{2x}$) which is one of the solutions, but the other one, $y = Ae^{-2x}$ ,is not present.

Comment: After thinking about it and playing around, I think that there are 2 valid substitutions for every homogeneous linear 2nd order ODE. The reason I only get the one solution from this is because I have only used the one substitution. I will investigate more and comment later.

Comment: The solution to the equation $y'+2y=z=Ae^{-x}$ is $y=Ae^{-x}+Be^{-2x}$. There is no "loss of solutions".

Comment: @Gonçalo $e^{2x}y'+2e^{2x}y$ = $Ae^x$, ($e^{2x}y$)' = $Ae^x$, $e^{2x}y$=$Ae^x$ how do i obtain the other solution?

Comment: oops I now see that I was forgetting the constant when integrating. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution is not correct. With your $z$ you get
$$
z'+z=[y''+2y']+[y'+2y]=y''+3y'+2y~~(=y'-y)
$$
These are the same coefficients, but in a different order, thus giving a different ODE.

If you take $z=y'+y$, then
$$
z'+z=y''+2y'+y=-2y
$$
which is a sensible first-order system with slightly smaller coefficients than with the standard $z=y'$.

Comment: My apologies, I miswrote the ODE, it should have been y''+3y'+2y =0 which I have now corrected.  Can you explain why the substitution only gives the one answer?

Comment: Why do you expect $e^{-3x}$? You should get $y=Ae^{-x}+Be^{-2x}$, each integration resulting in one integration factor.

Comment: Another blunder caused by me writing out the wrong ODE. I now see that i was forgetting the constant. Thanks for the help.